# Problem of correctly defining Hankel transforms

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, special-functions, integral-transforms, bessel-functions

I have found the definition of the $v$-th order Hankel transform in the book of A.D. Poularikas "Transforms and applications" in Chapter $9$:

$$H_{v}(f(s))=\int_{0}^{+ \infty} rf(r) J_{v}(sr) dr$$

where $J_{v}$ is the $v$-th order Bessel function of the first kind.

My questions are:

- If $f \in L^{2}(R^{+})$, is this transform well-defined? If it is the case $H_{v}(f)$ belongs to which set?.
- How do we find the convergence of $J_{v}$? They put directly on other papers  approximations of the Bessel function $J_{v}$. But what are the calculations to resolve those?
- Last but not least what is $v$? Is it an integer or a real number?

Comment: You can find more information on Hankel transfroms at https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HankelTransform.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_transform (which also gives an alternative definition).